# How to log exceptions in appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, error-handling, error-logging

```
try:
  #do something that raises an exception...
except:
  logging.error('Error Message')
```

I want more than just "Error Message" to show in the logs. I want to see the traceback, or at least what the exception was, in the logs as well. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: According to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you shouldn't really have an empty `except:` clause unless you are re-`raise`-ing the error. Otherwise a surprise exception could be raised and your app will continue along, unaware that it is in a completely hosed state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`logging.exception(msg[, *args])`

Logs a message with level ERROR on the root logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug(). Exception info is added to the logging message. This function should only be called from an exception handler.

http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.exception

Comment: There's also this awesome tool for App Engine called [ereporter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter.html) that sends you a daily email of exceptions from your app.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I use to log the entire stack trace:

```
import traceback
try:
    # your code
except:
    stacktrace = traceback.format_exc()
    logging.error("%s", stacktrace)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should help you

```
import logging

try:
    #exception code
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the logging details to Debug,Info,Warning,Error or Critical and set in your application. Debug would give you a lot of details.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

And you can get the logs of the particular filter in your appengine web console under /logs.